# Update query to set values from another table

Tags: java, sql

Can any one please tell me what's wrong in this query?

```
String squery="update Room set GuestDetails.GuestCode=Room.GuestCode, GuestDetails.Title=Room.Title, GuestDetails.FirstName=Room.FirstName, GuestDetails.LastName=Room.LastName, GuestDetails.Country=Room.Country, GuestDetails.State=Room.State, GuestDetails.City=Room.City, GuestDetails.ContactNo=Room.ContactNo from GuestDetails inner join Room on Room.RoomNo="+rn+" and GuestCode="+gc+"";
```

I am trying to update Room and set values from GuestDetails. If I enter GuestCode=1 the guest with GuestCode 1 should be set at RoomNo say 101. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have your table structure or data, but try as follows

```
UPDATE Room
   SET GuestDetails.GuestCode = Room.GuestCode,
       GuestDetails.Title = Room.Title,
       GuestDetails.FirstName = Room.FirstName,
       GuestDetails.LastName = Room.LastName,
       GuestDetails.Country = Room.Country,
       GuestDetails.State = Room.State,
       GuestDetails.City = Room.City,
       GuestDetails.ContactNo = Room.ContactNo
 where GuestDetails inner join Room on Room.RoomNo="+rn+" and GuestCode="+gc+
```

Use `where` instead of `from`